# Сравнить диапазон времени в двух листах и закрасить ячейки между диапазонами

Tags: excel, vba

Есть два листа. На первую страницу динамически поступают данные времени обновления баз данных. Во втором листе формируется время с помощью переноса времени. Задача в том, чтобы с помощью VBA закрашивались ячейки, которые соответствуют тому периоду времени, когда была сделано обновление.

Есть код, который мог бы работать, но что-то не хватает. Что делается не так? Ругается на 9 ошибку и неверный диапазон.

```
Option Explicit
Sub timeCFR()
    With Worksheets("Лист2")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(7, 5))
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=И(ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$B:$B, ПОИСКПОЗ(C$1, Лист1!$A:$A, 0))<=$B2, ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$C:$C, ПОИСКПОЗ(C$1, Лист1!$A:$A, 0))>=$B2)"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Пример первого листа:

```
   1       2        3 
DB_NAME  start     end
  DB1    20:30    21:02
  DB2    22:04    22:26
  DB3    19:05    22:10
```

Пример второго листа:

```
 1        2         3        4      5 
DAY      TIME      DB1      DB2    DB3
MON     19:05       '        '      '
        20:30       '        '      '
        21:02       '        '      '
        22:04       '        '      '
        22:10       '        '      '
        22:26       '        '      '
TUE     00:25       -        -      -
```

Comment: Избавьтесь от вложенных `With`.

Comment: @Akina, в таком случае ссылку на лист  придется  прописывать три раза. Но можно записать  *With Worksheets("Лист2").Range("C2:E7")*

Comment: Именно. Объединением.

Answer (score 0):

Косяк с разделителем (в русскоязычных формулах должна быть точка с запятой).

Пробуйте или

```
Formula1:="=AND(INDEX(Лист1!$B:$B, MATCH(C$1, Лист1!$A:$A, 0))<=$B2, INDEX(Лист1!$C:$C, MATCH(C$1, Лист1!$A:$A, 0))>=$B2)"
```

или

```
Formula1:="=И(ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$B:$B; ПОИСКПОЗ(C$1; Лист1!$A:$A; 0))<=$B2; ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$C:$C; ПОИСКПОЗ(C$1; Лист1!$A:$A; 0))>=$B2)"
```

Comment: Да, разделители исправил. Это потом уже заметил. Но всё равно Run-time Error 9 - Subscript out of range. Тем не менее, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub timeCFR()
    With Worksheets("Лист2").Range("C2:E7")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ЕСЛИ(ВПР(C$1;Лист1!$A$2:$C$100;2;0)<=$B2;ВПР(C$1;Лист1!$A$2:$C$100;3;0)>=$B2)"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Была ошибка в формуле.

Попутно: для *ИНДЕКС/ВПР* нежелательно задавать полные столбцы в диапазоне поиска - при отсутствии значения просматривается весь диапазон.

*ЕСЛИ* вместо *И* выгоднее - обрезаются лишние вычисления.

Вариант:

```
Sub timeCFR()
Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Worksheets("Лист2").Range("C2:E7")

    With rRng.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ЕСЛИ(ВПР(C$1;Лист1!$A$2:$C$100;2;0)<=$B2;ВПР(C$1;Лист1!$A$2:$C$100;3;0)>=$B2)"
        rRng.FormatConditions(.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With

    Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

'-------------------

Условное форматирование в видимой части экрана летуче (пересчитывается, когда не нужно), добавляет вес файлу. Если применяется *VBA*, то и красить можно в коде.

```
Sub timeCFR2()
Dim aInit(), aTime()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim lRw1 As Long, lRw2 As Long, lClmn As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        lRw1 = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        aInit = .Range("A1:C" & lRw1).Value
    End With

    With Worksheets("Лист2")
        lRw2 = .UsedRange.Rows.Count: lClmn = lRw1 + 1
        .Columns(3).Resize(, lClmn - 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        aTime = .Range("A1").Resize(lRw2, lClmn).Value

        For i = 2 To lRw2
            For j = 3 To lClmn
                For k = 2 To lRw1
                    If aTime(1, j) = aInit(k, 1) Then
                        If aTime(i, 2) >= aInit(k, 2) Then
                            If aTime(i, 2) <= aInit(k, 3) Then
                                If rRng Is Nothing Then
                                    Set rRng = .Cells(i, j) ' формируем диапазон
                                Else
                                    Set rRng = Union(rRng, .Cells(i, j)) 'пополняем диапазон
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rRng Is Nothing Then rRng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0): Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Если расположение DB на листах одинаково (на первом по строкам, на втором по столбцам), циклы по j и k заменить на счетчик

Comment: даже с таким вариантом пересмотренным, в моём случае идёт ругань на Run-time Error 9 - Subscript out of range, хотя, всё в порядке с виду. И ячейки на месте. С более выгодным вычислением это правда необходимо, благодарства за подсказку. И весь диапазон значений он будет применён в дальнейшем, так как таблица будет бесконечно расширяться за счёт поступления данных. А вообще верно, если говорить про статику.

Comment: Код рабочий, проверено. Ошибка говорит о том, что диапазон задан неверно. Проверьте имена листов, ссылки...

Comment: да, вероятно, названия другие. Это совсем упустить мог из виду. Проверено. Но на самой формуле условного форматирования выдал теперь вовсе 5 ошибку invalid procedure or argument. Это вообще загадка в моём excel получается. Проверяю формулу

Comment: Английские функции и разделитель запятая. Кириллические - точка с запятой... Какая таблица будет расширяться? По столбцам тоже?

Comment: да, таблица будет по Time расширяться и по столбцам DB. Но это уже не проблема дописать.